# Topology on the set of Homotopy Classes $[X, Y]$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and let $C(X, Y)$ be set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. Define an equivalence relation in $C(X, Y)$ setting:

$$f\sim g\iff f\ \textrm{is homotopic to}\ g.$$

Let $[X, Y]$ be the quotient $C(X, Y)/\sim$. Is there a "natural" topology in $[X, Y]$? Natural here should be taken in the context of homotopy theory.

Of course, it should be the quotient topology induced from the topology on $C(X, Y)$. But, what topology should I consider in $C(X, Y)$? The compact-open topology?

Thanks.

Comment: The compact-open topology is standard. But it's a little strange to take a topology on $[X, Y]$; you're taking $\pi_0$ of the mapping space and from a homotopy-theoretic point of view this is just a set. If it acquires a nontrivial quotient topology that is in some sense weird point-set stuff and not obviously homotopy-theoretically meaningful.

Comment: In the context of homotopy theory, it should always be taken with the discrete topology. What you are interested in is in the context of “wild algebraic topology”.

Comment: What are you considering doing with this topology?

Comment: I don't have a specific goal, but it seemed a natural question since we are "inside" the category of topological spaces.

Comment: Have you come accross the work of Jeremy Brazas ([for instance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3972))? He has studied the special case of your question of putting a group topology on the fundamental group of a space. The idea is that the more subtle structure should be useful in the study of spaces for which standard methods like covering theory cannot be applied.

Comment: I didn't know that paper. Thanks a lot, I'll check it.